# Can't get QGIS to keep my user-defined toolbar setup

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, toolbar, panel

I am working for an organization where we are trying to set up QGIS for all the employees so that it is as user-friendly as possible.

I am trying to set up the toolbars and panels to show only the most used features, I have tried to use the user-defined setup method within QGIS but it does not seem to keep the settings I picked. Every time I start QGIS it shows the right setup but after it loads completely it resets to default and shows the default setup every time.

Comment: Does it have to do maybe with writing permissions to the installation drive?

Comment: To make this clear: You're trying to remove single buttons from the toolbars, you're not talking about rearranging the toolbars themselves?